# CouchDb Database with many revisions

Tags: ionic3, couchdb, pouchdb

We have an app that works with PouchDb in it and CouchDb as database server. One of databases has grow with too many revisions. It have 839 docs but when I sync with app it insert 8500 items (some docs have more than 300 revision). I was looking around and I have thought I have to work with revs_limit in pouchdb but it doesn't work.

```
this.db = new PouchDB(perfil.profile.bd, 
                     {auto_compaction: true,revs_limit:10}
);
```

I tried auto_compaction too but this no resolve my problem.

Is possible remove revisions at server side (in couchdb) to avoid my app sync more than 8000 items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to replication from CDB there is nothing to do with revs_limit on PDB side - it affects only docs created and mantained locally in PDB, not server.
Put desired number on _revs_limit CDB endpoint.
In my code it works like:

```
CDB.setRevsLimit = (dbName, limit)=> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
    let payload = putOptions;
    payload.path = dbName + '/_revs_limit';
    let req = http.request(payload, (res) => {
      let data = '';
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', (chunk)=> {data += chunk})
      res.on('end', ()=> {
        if (res.statusCode === 200) {
          return resolve('setRevsLimit_done')
        } else {
          return reject(res.statusCode + ': ' + data)
        }
      })
    });
    req.on('error', (err)=> {return reject('CDB.setRevsLimit ERR: ' + err)})
    req.write(JSON.stringify(limit));
    req.end();
  })
};
```

After you may want to run purge and compaction on CDB side

Comment: Ok, thanks.. now it’s working but purge is not working.. I receive a response like “not supported”. Do you know if I have to have some special configuration?

Comment: Nothing special if you construct your request in correct way. Check CDB docs, there everything is quite straightforward